# C++ Eigen: How to concatenate matrices dynamically (pointer issue?)

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

I have the following problem:
I have several partial (eigen) MatrixXds I want to concatenate to another, larger, MatrixXd variable I only have as a pointer. However, both the size of the smaller matrices and their number are dynamic, so I cannot use the << operator easily.

So I'm trying the following (the smaller matrices are stored in list_subdiagrams, obviously, and basis->cols() defines the number of matrices), using Eigen's MatrixXd block funtionality:

```
// sd[] contains the smaller matrices to be concatenated; all are of the same size
// col defines the total number of smaller matrices

MatrixXd* ret = new MatrixXd(sd[0]->rows(), col*sd[0]->cols());
for (int i=0; i<col; ++i){
    ret->block(0, i*sd[0]->cols(), sd[0]->rows(), sd[0]->cols()) = *(sd[i]);
}
```

This, unfortunately, appears to somehow overwrite some part of the *ret variable - for before the assignment via the block, the size is (in my test-case) correctly shown as being 2x1. After the assignment it becomes 140736006011136x140736006011376 ...

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean you don't know the size? You can use the member functions `cols()/rows()` to get the size. Also, I assume by concatenation you mean direct sum? In that case, you can do something like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

int main()
{
    Eigen::MatrixXd *A = new Eigen::MatrixXd(2, 2);
    Eigen::MatrixXd *B = new Eigen::MatrixXd(3, 3);
    *A << 1, 2, 3, 4;
    *B << 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13;


    Eigen::MatrixXd *result = new Eigen::MatrixXd(A->rows() + B->rows(), A->cols() + B->cols());
    result->Zero(A->rows() + B->rows(), A->cols() + B->cols());
    result->block(0, 0, A->rows(), A->cols()) = *A;
    result->block(A->rows(), A->cols(), B->rows(), B->cols()) = *B;

    std::cout << *result << std::endl;

    delete A;
    delete B;
    delete result;
}
```

So first make sure it works for 2 matrices, test it, then extend it to `N`.

Comment: Thank you. The first version of your post did not work - one cannot initialize a matrix pointer directly to zero. This one, however, works. I'll update my post to be more precise.

Comment: So - I looked over the difference between the different snippets again, and it seems that my initial problem was that I did not initialize the matrix to specific values ... so assigning the memory with "new" apparently is not enough. Would you agree with this assessment? Thanks again!

Comment: @cleros Yes that's correct, using `new` does not initialize anything in the matrix. In fact, even `MatrixXd mat(2,2);` DOES NOT initialize the elements to zero. You need to initialize the matrix explicitly.

Comment: @cleros why exactly do you use pointers instead of simply `MatrixXd` (or references to it)? The `MatrixXd` itself performs memory allocation etc, so there is no visible advantage of using pointers. Also, it is highly unlikely you'll use virtual functions with `Eigen`...

Comment: I need it as a pointer because the snippet was actually part of a larger, recursive, function. So I am both using the pointer as an argument and as a return value. Since Eigen recommends using a pointer for arguments and return values, I am sticking to these.

Comment: can as well use references/const references as input, then return by value, the compiler will optimize due to return value optimization