# Is there a functionality in C++ to create a block matrix as simple as Python's `numpy.bmat`?

Tags: python, c++, numpy, boost

Is there a functionality in C++ to create a block matrix as simple as [numpy.bmat](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.bmat.html)?

Example:

*Python*:

```
m = np.bmat([[A, B], [C, D]])
```

*C++* The only approach I know of is using [boost::numeric::ublas::project](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/operations_overview.html):

```
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>

boost::numeric::ublas::matrix m;

//...

r1 = boost::numeric::ublas::range(i1, i2);
r2 = boost::numeric::ublas::range(i3, i4);
boost::numeric::ublas::project(m, r1, r2) = A;

// repeat code above for other submatrices, each time calculating the appropriate indices
```

Comment: `bmat` may have a simple syntax, but the code itself isn't that simple.  Click on the `[source]` link of the documentation.

Comment: It seems based on concatanation. If there isn't a function in C++ for that, maybe it can be created... I'll try to think on one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be easier to use [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialBlockOperations.html). Here is an example program:

```
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>
using Eigen::MatrixXd;
int main()
{
  MatrixXd m(2,2);
  m(0,0) = 3;
  m(1,0) = 2.5;
  m(0,1) = -1;
  m(1,1) = m(1,0) + m(0,1);
  std::cout << m << std::endl;

  MatrixXd mx(4,4);
  mx.block<2,2>(0,0) << m;
  mx.block<2,2>(2,2) << m;
  std::cout << mx << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: this may help further: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928374/c-eigen-how-to-concatenate-matrices-dynamically-pointer-issue